# How to test a button click in React with TypeScript, Jest and Enzyme

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, enzyme

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript. I'm doing my component tests using Jest and Enzyme. I'm also using React Navigation

I'm struggling to write the unit test for clicking my button.

Here is the component's code (just the render function):

```
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          raised
          title={strings.painButtonTitle}
          buttonStyle={styles.painButton}
          titleStyle={styles.title}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("QuestionsScreen")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Now here is the unit test.

```
  describe("interaction", () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    let props: Props;
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps({});
      wrapper = shallow(<HomeScreen {...props} />);
    });

    describe("clicking the Pain Button", () => {
      it("should navigate to the 'QuestionsScreen'", () => {
        wrapper.find("Button").simulate("click");

        expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });
    });
  });
```

This fails and claims the `navigation.navigate` function - which is mocked using jest.fn() - is never called.

I assume it has something to do with providing an error function to the button. The problem is, I can't not do that, since I need to call with the argument `"QuestionsScreen"`. So I can't do something like `onPress={this.navigation.navigate)` and then miraculously call `"QuestionsScreen"`, can I?

How can I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["Common Gotchas" section for `simulate`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas) says that "even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event, .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get the onClick prop and call it."

That behavior can be seen in the `Enzyme` source code [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js#L418-L429) and [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9d2ebb7b35197739c3f30a3a0d9a6c21dd6ee95a/packages/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js#L75).

So the line `wrapper.find("Button").simulate("click");` ends up trying to call the `onClick` prop of the `Button` which doesn't exist so it essentially does nothing.

[This post](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/991#issuecomment-313203726) from an Airbnb dev recommends invoking props directly and avoiding `simulate`.

Here is a modified test that invokes the `onPress` prop directly:

```ts
it("should navigate to the 'QuestionsScreen'", () => {
  wrapper.find(Button).props().onPress({} as any);

  expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);   // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: I only have one issue: I get the error: `Property 'onPress' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes'.` How can I fix that? This is how I define my wrapper: `let wrapper: ShallowWrapper<{}, {}, HomeScreen>;` And then `wrapper = shallow(<HomeScreen {...props} />);`

Comment: I also tried `wrapper.find("Button").prop("onPress")({} as any);` which gives the error: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: Another update: Now I imported Button and did what you wrote verbatim: `wrapper
          .find(Button)
          .props()
          .onPress({} as any);` - without putting a quotes around Button. Then I get the error: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

Comment: Made a new stackoverflow question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697779/unit-testing-in-react-with-typescript-jest-and-enzyme-cannot-invoke-an-object

Comment: oh yeah, I should have pointed out that I used `Button` directly so that the type of the props could be inferred

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question with you. I tried `simulate("click")` but failed because there's no `onClick` property of the component.

My way was to change the test case to `wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit")` because my navigation function was defined in the submit property of the form.