# Unit testing in React with TypeScript, Jest and Enzyme: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript. I'm doing my component tests using Jest and Enzyme. I'm also using React Navigation

[In my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692824/how-to-test-a-button-click-in-react-with-typescript-jest-and-enzyme) [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10149510/brian-lives-outdoors) explained to me how to correctly test the press of a button. My problem is that the buttons `onPress` prop may be undefined. Let me show you the code:

```or-tag
export class HomeScreen extends Component<Props, object> {
  // ... navigationOptions and stuff

  handlePress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("QuestionsScreen");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          raised={true}
          title={strings.painButtonTitle}
          buttonStyle={styles.painButton}
          titleStyle={styles.title}
          onPress={this.handlePress}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the test I write for testing the interaction with the button:

```or-tag
describe("interaction", () => {
  const props = createTestProps({});
  const wrapper = shallow<HomeScreen>(<HomeScreen {...props} />);

  describe("clicking the Pain Button", () => {
    it("should navigate to the 'QuestionsScreen'", () => {
      wrapper.instance().handlePress = jest.fn();
      wrapper.find(Button).prop("onPress")({} as any);

      expect(wrapper.instance().handlePress).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is here that my test won't run, because the linter says that `onPress` may be undefined:

```or-tag
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
```

How can I fix this?

I tried wrapping my code in an if statement like this:

```or-tag
if (typeof wrapper.find(Button).prop("onPress") !== undefined) {
  wrapper.find(Button).prop("onPress")({} as any);
}
```

But this also does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either use the [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) like this:

```
wrapper.find(Button).prop("onPress")!({} as any);
```

...or assign the handler to a variable and call it behind a guard like this:

```
const handler = wrapper.find(Button).prop("onPress");
if (handler) {
  handler({} as any);
}
```

Comment: Ah, you must be using something other than the standard `Button` from `react-native` since the standard `Button` [requires the `onPress` prop](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6f05b6429bdd9842e7d0cc12612aa85d4bb48b75/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L6985) and wouldn't cause this error

Comment: Yup. I'm using [React Native Element's Button](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, the test passes now. Just on follow up question: I tried the test using a `handleClick` function as a middle man, which I then mocked. [I made a gist for you](https://gist.github.com/janhesters/645de8ee8f61b99a36146d5d2398ac4c), so you can see what I mean. The test unfortunately fails. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `this.handlePress` is getting passed to `Button` directly.  Then `this.handlePress` gets replaced by the spy, but the component is not re-rendered so the `Button` still has the old `this.handlePress` and it gets called instead of the spy.  (Interestingly, the component isn't re-rendered even when calling `wrapper.update()`...something else besides just `this.handlePress` has to change for it to get re-rendered).  You can get that test to pass by using a lambda like this: `onPress={() => this.handlePress()}` so that when `onPress` is invoked it calls the current `this.handlePress`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to force rerender a component without using `wrapper.update()`? Because even though in this case it doesn't matter, it could matter for PureComponent's where one would have to avoid using lambdas.

Comment: I just looked at the test a little closer.  Trying to force the component to re-render in a way it normally wouldn't so the spy on `handlePress` works is an *XY Problem*.  Since `handlePress` is just an internal implementation detail it doesn't need to be tested, the spy should be on the `navigation.navigate` passed as a prop.

Comment: Sounds legit! Thank you 

Comment: Could you also be so kind and have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716212/typescript-either-or-for-functions-passed-down-through-several-components-in-re)? It destroys my unit tests, because none of them will run as long as I have that ts error described in the aforementioned question.