# TypeScript: Either or for functions passed down through several components in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I'm writing a React Native application using TypeScript.

I have a component `EmotionsRater` that accepts one of two types: Emotion or Need. It should also either accept a function of type `rateNeed` or `rateEmotion`. I combined these types to one called `rateBoth` using the `|` operator. And it passes this combined type down to another component called `EmotionsRaterItem`. The problem is that `EmotionsRaterItem` then claims:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'rateBoth' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I provided the boiled down code for all relevant components below.

QuestionsScreen.tsx:

```
// ... imports

export type rateEmotion = (rating: number, emotion: Emotion) => void;
export type rateNeed = (rating: number, emotion: Need) => void;

export interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}

export interface State {
  readonly emotions: Emotion[];
  readonly needs: Need[];
}

let EMOTIONS_ARRAY: Emotion[] = // ... some array of emotions

let NEEDS_ARRAY: Need[] = // ... some array of needs

export class QuestionsScreen extends Component<Props, State> {
  static navigationOptions = // ... React Navigation Stuff

  readonly state = {
    emotions: EMOTIONS_ARRAY.slice(),
    needs: NEEDS_ARRAY.slice()
  };

  swiper: any;

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    // ... code to reset the emotions
  };

  toggleEmotion = (emotion: Emotion) => {
    // ... unrelated code for the <EmotionsPicker />
  };

  rateEmotion: rateEmotion = (rating, emotion) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      emotions: prevState.emotions.map(val => {
        if (val.name === emotion.name) {
          val.rating = rating;
        }
        return val;
      })
    }));
  };

  rateNeed: rateNeed = (rating, need) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      need: prevState.emotions.map(val => {
        if (val.name === need.name) {
          val.rating = rating;
        }
        return val;
      })
    }));
  };

  goToIndex = (targetIndex: number) => {
    const currentIndex = this.swiper.state.index;
    const offset = targetIndex - currentIndex;
    this.swiper.scrollBy(offset);
  };

  render() {
    const { emotions, needs } = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ bottom: "always" }}>
        <Swiper
          style={styles.wrapper}
          showsButtons={false}
          loop={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          showsPagination={false}
          ref={component => (this.swiper = component)}
        >
          <EmotionsPicker
            emotions={emotions}
            toggleEmotion={this.toggleEmotion}
            goToIndex={this.goToIndex}
          />
          <EmotionsRater
            emotions={emotions.filter(emotion => emotion.chosen)}
            rateEmotion={this.rateEmotion}
            goToIndex={this.goToIndex}
          />
          <EmotionsRater
            emotions={needs}
            rateEmotion={this.rateNeed}
            goToIndex={this.goToIndex}
            tony={true}
          />
        </Swiper>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionsScreen;
```

EmotionsRater.tsx:

```
// ... imports

export type rateBoth = rateEmotion | rateNeed;

export interface Props {
  emotions: Emotion[] | Need[];
  rateEmotion: rateBoth;
  goToIndex: (targetIndex: number) => void;
  tony?: boolean;
}

export interface DefaultProps {
  readonly tony: boolean;
}

export class EmotionsRater extends PureComponent<Props & DefaultProps> {
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    tony: false
  };

  keyExtractor = (item: Emotion | Need, index: number): string =>
    item.name + index.toString();

  renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Emotion | Need }) => (
    <EmotionsRaterItem emotion={item} rateEmotion={this.props.rateEmotion} />
  );

  renderHeader = () => {
    const { tony } = this.props;
    return (
      <ListItem
        title={tony ? strings.needsTitle : strings.raterTitle}
        titleStyle={styles.title}
        bottomDivider={true}
        containerStyle={styles.headerContainer}
        leftIcon={tony ? badIcon : goodIcon}
        rightIcon={tony ? goodIcon : badIcon}
      />
    );
  };

  goBack = () => {
    this.props.goToIndex(0);
  };

  goForth = () => {
    this.props.goToIndex(2);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList<Emotion | Need>
          style={styles.container}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          data={this.props.emotions}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        />
        <ButtonFooter
          firstButton={{
            disabled: false,
            onPress: this.goBack,
            title: strings.goBack
          }}
          secondButton={{
            disabled: false,
            onPress: this.goForth,
            title: strings.done
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default EmotionsRater;
```

EmotionsRaterItem.tsx:

```
// ... imports

export interface Props {
  emotion: Emotion | Need;
  rateEmotion: rateBoth;
}

export interface State {
  readonly rating: number;
}

export class EmotionsRaterItem extends PureComponent<Props, State> {
  readonly state = { rating: this.props.emotion.rating };

  ratingCompleted = (rating: number) => {
    this.setState({ rating });
    this.props.rateEmotion(rating, this.props.emotion);
    // This    ^^^^^^^^^^^ throws the error mentioned in the post.
  };

  render() {
    const { emotion } = this.props;
    const { rating } = this.state;
    const color = getColor(rating);
    return (
      <ListItem
        title={emotion.name}
        bottomDivider={true}
        rightTitle={String(Math.round(rating * 100))}
        rightTitleStyle={{ color: color.hex("rgb") }}
        rightContentContainerStyle={styles.rightContentContainer}
        subtitle={
          <Slider
            value={emotion.rating}
            thumbTintColor={activeColor}
            minimumTrackTintColor={color.hex("rgb")}
            maximumTrackTintColor={color.alpha(0.4).hex("rgba")}
            step={0.01}
            onValueChange={this.ratingCompleted}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default EmotionsRaterItem;
```

What is going on? Why doesn't TypeScript know that `rateBoth` is one of two functions and therefore callable?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [Estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus)'s comment I added the code here instead of gists.

Comment: The question should contain all code that is necessary for understanding. Gists can go away but question body can't. If the snippets are too big, consider making it smaller by removing irrelevant parts, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you feel that showing things in whole may be beneficial, consider providing a working demo, both stackblitz and codesandbox provide React+TS setups.

Comment: @estus I added the code to the questions. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EmotionsRaterItem` has a function of type `rateBoth`, then that function either requires an `Emotion` or requires a `Need`, but the caller does not know which of the type is required.  Hence, under current TypeScript semantics, it's impossible to call the function.  (You could imagine that maybe passing an argument that is *both* an `Emotion` and a `Need` should work, but TypeScript isn't that smart; see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).)

Instead, you could make `EmotionsRater` and `EmotionsRaterItem` generic in the type `T` of the item they are working on (either `Emotion` or `Need`).  (Of course, [generic components are unsound in general](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17949), but it looks like the problem won't occur in your scenario.)  Semi-complete example:

**QuestionsScreen.tsx**

```
// ... imports
import { Component } from "react";
import EmotionsRater from "./EmotionsRater";
import * as React from "react";

export interface Emotion {
  emotionBrand: undefined;
  name: string;
  rating: number;
}
export interface Need {
  needBrand: undefined;
  name: string;
  rating: number;
}

export type rateEmotion = (rating: number, emotion: Emotion) => void;
export type rateNeed = (rating: number, emotion: Need) => void;

export interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}

export interface State {
  readonly emotions: Emotion[];
  readonly needs: Need[];
}

let EMOTIONS_ARRAY: Emotion[] = []; // ... some array of emotions

let NEEDS_ARRAY: Need[] = []; // ... some array of needs

export class QuestionsScreen extends Component<Props, State> {
  static navigationOptions; // ... React Navigation Stuff

  readonly state = {
    emotions: EMOTIONS_ARRAY.slice(),
    needs: NEEDS_ARRAY.slice()
  };

  swiper: any;

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    // ... code to reset the emotions
  };

  toggleEmotion = (emotion: Emotion) => {
    // ... unrelated code for the <EmotionsPicker />
  };

  rateEmotion: rateEmotion = (rating, emotion) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      emotions: prevState.emotions.map(val => {
        if (val.name === emotion.name) {
          val.rating = rating;
        }
        return val;
      })
    }));
  };

  rateNeed: rateNeed = (rating, need) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      need: prevState.emotions.map(val => {
        if (val.name === need.name) {
          val.rating = rating;
        }
        return val;
      })
    }));
  };

  goToIndex = (targetIndex: number) => {
    const currentIndex = this.swiper.state.index;
    const offset = targetIndex - currentIndex;
    this.swiper.scrollBy(offset);
  };

  render() {
    const { emotions, needs } = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ bottom: "always" }}>
        <Swiper
          style={styles.wrapper}
          showsButtons={false}
          loop={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          showsPagination={false}
          ref={component => (this.swiper = component)}
        >
          <EmotionsPicker
            emotions={emotions}
            toggleEmotion={this.toggleEmotion}
            goToIndex={this.goToIndex}
          />
          <EmotionsRater
            emotions={emotions.filter(emotion => emotion.chosen)}
            rateEmotion={this.rateEmotion}
            goToIndex={this.goToIndex}
          />
          <EmotionsRater
            emotions={needs}
            rateEmotion={this.rateNeed}
            goToIndex={this.goToIndex}
            tony={true}
          />
        </Swiper>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionsScreen;
```

**EmotionsRater.tsx**

```
// ... imports
import { PureComponent } from "react";
import * as React from "react";
import { Emotion, Need } from "./QuestionsScreen";
import EmotionsRaterItem from "./EmotionsRaterItem";

export interface Props<T extends Emotion | Need> {
  emotions: T[];
  rateEmotion: (rating: number, emotion: T) => void;
  goToIndex: (targetIndex: number) => void;
  tony?: boolean;
}

export interface DefaultProps {
  readonly tony: boolean;
}

export class EmotionsRater<T extends Emotion | Need> extends PureComponent<Props<T> & DefaultProps> {
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    tony: false
  };

  keyExtractor = (item: Emotion | Need, index: number): string =>
    item.name + index.toString();

  renderItem = ({ item }: { item: T }) => (
    <EmotionsRaterItem emotion={item} rateEmotion={this.props.rateEmotion} />
  );

  renderHeader = () => {
    const { tony } = this.props;
    return (
      <ListItem
        title={tony ? strings.needsTitle : strings.raterTitle}
        titleStyle={styles.title}
        bottomDivider={true}
        containerStyle={styles.headerContainer}
        leftIcon={tony ? badIcon : goodIcon}
        rightIcon={tony ? goodIcon : badIcon}
      />
    );
  };

  goBack = () => {
    this.props.goToIndex(0);
  };

  goForth = () => {
    this.props.goToIndex(2);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList<T>
          style={styles.container}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          data={this.props.emotions}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        />
        <ButtonFooter
          firstButton={{
            disabled: false,
            onPress: this.goBack,
            title: strings.goBack
          }}
          secondButton={{
            disabled: false,
            onPress: this.goForth,
            title: strings.done
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default EmotionsRater;
```

**EmotionsRaterItem.tsx**

```
// ... imports
import { PureComponent } from "react";
import * as React from "react";
import { Emotion, Need } from "./QuestionsScreen";

export interface Props<T extends Emotion | Need> {
  emotion: T;
  rateEmotion: (rating: number, emotion: T) => void;
}

export interface State {
  readonly rating: number;
}

export class EmotionsRaterItem<T extends Emotion | Need> extends PureComponent<Props<T>, State> {
  readonly state = { rating: this.props.emotion.rating };

  ratingCompleted = (rating: number) => {
    this.setState({ rating });
    this.props.rateEmotion(rating, this.props.emotion);
  };

  render() {
    const { emotion } = this.props;
    const { rating } = this.state;
    const color = getColor(rating);
    return (
      <ListItem
        title={emotion.name}
        bottomDivider={true}
        rightTitle={String(Math.round(rating * 100))}
        rightTitleStyle={{ color: color.hex("rgb") }}
        rightContentContainerStyle={styles.rightContentContainer}
        subtitle={
          <Slider
            value={emotion.rating}
            thumbTintColor={activeColor}
            minimumTrackTintColor={color.hex("rgb")}
            maximumTrackTintColor={color.alpha(0.4).hex("rgba")}
            step={0.01}
            onValueChange={this.ratingCompleted}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default EmotionsRaterItem;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and helping me. I tried your code and it works. But if writing a generic component like this is bad practice, how else is one supposed to create a reusable component for more that one type?

Comment: I'd say that using generic components is OK practice as long as you avoid the unsound cases.  As long as you never write a render method that _conditionally_ generates calls to the same generic component with different type arguments, you'll be fine.  (The calls from `QuestionsScreen` to `EmotionsRater` are OK because they are unconditional.)  I've thought about a way to solve the unsoundness, but I haven't implemented it, and the problem comes up so rarely that I suspect many developers wouldn't be interested in adopting additional safeguards even if they were available.